# Give an example of a closed bounded subset of $l_\infty$ that is not totally bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, lp-spaces

I need to give an example of a closed bounded subset of $l_\infty$ (the collection of all bounded real sequences) that is not totally bounded.

**Question:** How do I do this? What would a subset of a collection like $l_\infty$ look like? Would this be a collection of bounded real sequences, or would this be a subset of the range of all the bounded real sequences?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the supremum norm, i.e. $\|\{x_n\}\| = \sup_n |x_n|$?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251548/set-that-is-bounded-but-not-totally-bounded-reading-textbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that you have an answer here (but this is just the same answer to which Math1000 posted a link in the comments): for each $n\in\mathbb N$, define $e(n)\in l^\infty$ by$$e(n)_k=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }n=k\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$The the set $E=\{e(n)\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ is bounded, being a subset of the closed ball centered at $0$ with radius $1$. But the distance between any two distinct elements of $E$ is $1$. Therefore, there is no finite union of open balls with radius $\frac12$ containing $E$.

Comment: The closed unit ball of any infinite dimensional normed linear space is a closed bounded set which is not totally bounded.

Answer (score 0):

For $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $x_k = \{x_n(k)\}_{n=0}^\infty$ where
\begin{gather}
x_n(k) = \begin{cases} 0 & n < k\\
2^{k-n} & n\geq k
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
so, $x_0 = \big(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots\big)$, $x_1 = \big(0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots\big)$, and so on. The set is bounded as $||x_k||_\infty = \frac{1}{2}$, but $||x_j - x_k||_\infty = \frac{1}{2}$, and so the set could not be covered by finitely many balls with radius $< \frac{1}{2}$.